# an other definition of adherent value for a sequence in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in a topological space and $\ell$ an adherent value for $(x_n)$.

I need to prove the equivalence of these two definitions

$$
[\forall V\in\mathcal{V}_{\ell}, |\{n, x_n\in V\}|=+\infty]\Longleftrightarrow [\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_{\ell}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists k\in\mathbb{N}: k\geq n \Rightarrow x_n\in V ]
$$

the difficulty is to prove that $
[\forall V\in\mathcal{V}_{\ell}, |\{n, x_n\in V\}|=+\infty]\Rightarrow [\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_{\ell}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists k\in\mathbb{N}: k\geq n \Rightarrow x_n\in V ]
$

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial, a subset of $\Bbb N$ is infinite iff it is unbounded above (which is what the right hand condition states).

A more commmon name for $\ell$ is a cluster point (of a sequence), or accumulation point.